# psqlodbca.so: Não é possivel abrir arquivo de objetos compartilhado: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado

Tags: postgresql, mysql, odbc

Não consigo migrar o banco do PostegreSql para o mysql devido a esse erro:

> psqlodbca.so: Não é possível abrir arquivo de objetos compartilhado:
>   Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado

Estou usando o ubuntu 64 Postgresql 9x e workbench 6.x, como devo proceder?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> String de conexão: ODBC connection string: DRIVER=PostgreSQL
>   ANSI;SERVER=127.0.0.1;PORT=5432;DATABASE=financeira;UID=postgres;UseDeclareFetch=1;

Comment: Não entendi, você está tentando usar o MySQL Workbench para acessar o Postgres?

Comment: realizar uma migração do banco postgresql para o mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que você não possui o driver `ODBC` do Postgres instalado no seu sistema.

Você pode fazer isso utilizando o gerenciador de pacotes `apt-get`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install odbc-postgresql
```

Ou baixar manualmente o pacote `.deb` contendo o *driver* para `Ubuntu 17.04 (Zesty Zapus)`:

```
$ wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/psqlodbc/odbc-postgresql_09.05.0400-2_amd64.deb
```

E depois instalar o pacote `.deb` manualmente:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i odbc-postgresql_09.05.0400-2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Apos executar o comando recebi essa mensagem: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: e continua repetindo o mesmo erro: Could not connect to Source DBMS.
[00000] [iODBC][Driver Manager]psqlodbca.so: Não é possivel abrir arquivo de objetos compartilhado: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado (0) (SQLDriverConnect)

Comment: @alexjosesilva: Resposta editada. Algum avanço?

Comment: Mesmo erro. Reiniciei o S.O.

Comment: @alexjosesilva: tente manualmente, qual é o erro retornado ?

Comment: como inserir o odbc dentro do workbench ??

Comment: @alexjosesilva: Instalando o driver ODBC do Postgres no seu Ubuntu, da forma como eu expliquei na resposta.

Comment: o erro continua...

Comment: você executou os comandos como root? tentou das duas formas que eu expliquei? você tem certeza que o pacote foi instalado ?

Comment: sim...usei o root fiz as duas instalações

Comment: ja habiliteir no php.ini o postgresql

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67665/discussion-between-alexjosesilva-and-lacobus).